# Change a progress bar width automatically without get down away from its position

Tags: html, css

Firstly, the following is the normal form of progress bar before change window size

[image]

Secondly, the following is the form of progress bar after change window size

[image]

**How to make the progress bar stable in the same place always, when change the window resolution adapts with window size ?**

HTML:

```
<div id="controls_container">
    <a id="addFile">
        <span class='icon-uniF0FE'></span>
        <span>Add</span>
    </a>
    <a id="beginUpload">
        <span class='icon-upload'></span>
        <span>Upload</span>
    </a>
    <div id="progressAll_container">
        <div id="progressAll"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#controls_container {
}

#progressAll_container {
    width:81%;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid #AED0EA;
    vertical-align:top;
}
#progressAll {
    width:0%;
    height:2em;
    text-align:center;
    color:#3395C6;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #EEF6FB, #CDE5F4);
    line-height:32px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [`calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) in your Progress container.

## snippet

```css
#progressAll_container {
  width:calc(100% - 91px);
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #AED0EA;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size:0 /*fix inline-block gap*/
}
#progressAll {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2em;
  text-align: center; 
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eef6fb 0%, #cde5f4 100%);
  line-height: 32px;
  font-size:16px /*fix inline-block gap*/
}
```

```html
<div id="controls_container">
  <a id="addFile">
    <span class='icon-uniF0FE'></span>
    <span>Add</span>
  </a>
  <a id="beginUpload">
    <span class='icon-upload'></span>
    <span>Upload</span>
  </a>
  <div id="progressAll_container">
    <div id="progressAll"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The only bad thing for `calc` function it is not supported in all browsers.

Comment: take a look [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc), supported in all major browsers with IE9+ (IE9 works because we are not applying `calc` to `background`but to `width`)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in jquery way. Hope this help.

```js
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).resize(function(){
               var bar_width = $("#controls_container").width()-($("#addFile").outerWidth()+$("#beginUpload").outerWidth());
               $("#progressAll_container").outerWidth(bar_width-(bar_width*0.05));
            });
    });
```

```css
#controls_container {
}

#progressAll_container {
    width:81%;
    display:inline-block;
  height:81%;
    border:1px solid #AED0EA;
    vertical-align:top;
}
#progressAll {
    width:100%;
    height:2em;
    text-align:center;
    color:#3395C6;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #EEF6FB 0%, #CDE5F4 100%);
    line-height:32px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="controls_container">
          <a id="addFile">
            <span class='icon-uniF0FE'></span>
            <span>Add</span>
          </a>
          <a id="beginUpload">
            <span class='icon-upload'></span>
            <span>Upload</span>
          </a>
          <div id="progressAll_container">
            <div id="progressAll">100%</div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you deserve **+1**.

Comment: Thank you very much. And did you need to support css3 that IE is below 9?

Comment: It is better I do that.